# Visual Basic Login Form Query

Tags: sql-server, vb6

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
 Adodc1.Recordset.MoveFirst
 Do While Not Adodc1.Recordset.EOF
        If Adodc1.Recordset.Fields(0) <> txtuser.Text Or Adodc1.Recordset.Fields(1) <>   txtPassword.Text Then

            MsgBox "Please verify login details", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Login Denied"
            txtuser.SetFocus
            txtuser.Text = ""
            txtPassword.Text = ""
        Else
            Unload Me
            Load Main
            Main.Show
        End If
        Adodc1.Recordset.MoveNext
        Loop
End Sub
```

I would appreciate it if someone looked at the code snippet above and told me if any changes need be made! This is the code I use for a login form that connects to a SQL SERVER 2005 DB! Now why isn't this working? It seems to ONLY fetch the data from the first row of the two columns, not the rows that follow?

Answer (score 2):

I would take a step back and rewrite all of this.  You should be sending the database the username and password, not sending every username and password to your application and looping through it. Let the DBMS do the work for you.  I would also suggest that you refrain from storing passwords as plain text (as it appears you are doing).  This information is general and can be found by searching, but if you're having a particular problem, post back.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions and those I will take care of in the later stages, but right now the above code (how much ever general it may be) isn't clear to me, I can't find faults with it :s Why does it fetch only the first row??

Comment: Why does it fetch only the first row? Who can tell? There is no query in your code. That's why colithium is correct in telling you to rethink the way to write database code. Drag-n-drop DB controls are something MS should have never offered.

Comment: Then, here is the part where it connects to the DB --Adodc1.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MyServer\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_connection=yes;DATABASE=Testingz;" Adodc1.RecordSource = "Select * from Security" Set lblBind.DataSource = Adodc1